# How can I get metadata from video - Flutter DESKTOP

Tags: flutter, dart, video, mp4, flutter-ffmpeg

I'm developing a desktop app with flutter, and I gotta get the metadata information.
I've been trying to use flutter_ffmpeg, but It does not have support to flutter desktop. Is there another way to do that for flutter desktop?